# How to show that $A_{10}$ contains an element of order $15$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show that $A_{10}$ contains an element of order $15$?

The answer to this was,

$(12345)(678)$

---

**How did they come about this answer?**

I noticed on other sites, on similar questions of same order but different A_#, the answer is basically the same, one having order 3 and other having order 5.

Answer (score 3):

We know the composition of a $k$-cycle with an $l$-cycle has order $lcm(k,l)$ if they are disjoint.  Further, a $k$-cycle is an even permutation if $k$ is odd.  Hence, we simply need two disjoint cycles, one of length 3 and one of length 5 since $lcm(3,5) = 15$.

Certainly your permutation is not unique.  We could also have, for example, $(1,4,3)(5,9,8,6,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $\sigma$ is a product of 2 permutations with disjoint support, then the order of $\sigma$ is the lcm of both orders.

One simple way
to see that is that the group of integers preserving
both permutations is $$o_1\Bbb Z \cap o_2\Bbb Z= \text{lcm}(o_1,o_2) \Bbb Z.$$

Hence as $15 = 3\times 5$ and $3+5<10$, there is element of order $15$.

Comment: So if I had something of the order 20, I can have one permutation of order 4 and another of order 5?  Since 20 = 4x5 and 4+5 < 20?

Comment: yes, for the same reason (you need to find an element of order 4, just take a 4cycle): (1234)(56789) should do the job

Comment: and this is 5+4<10, not 20 !

Comment: OH okay.  If it happens to be equal or greater than 10, what would happen?

Comment: you have to find another way... split un a product of more than 2 permutations.

Comment: btw, be carefull with my previous answer:  (1234)(56789) is not a product of elements of $A_{10}$

Comment: If I had A_10 of order 30, I can't do 5 and 6, since 5+6>10, and 2,3,5 is = 10, and I can't think of another combination that would work...so there's not possibility for this then?

Comment: No there is not. To complete the proof, invoke the existence of the decomposition in disjoint permutations and this formula.

Comment: (1234) is not in $A_{10}$ !

Comment: Because order 4 does not divide 10, correct?

Comment: no: because (1234) is a product of an odd number of 2cycles

Comment: The product of a $4$-cycle and a $5$-cycle is an odd permutation, which isn't in $A_{10}$. If you have an element $a$ of order $20$, $b=a^4$ has order $5$ and $c=a^5$ has order $4$, while $b^4c=a^{21}=a$.

Comment: @mookid What you have written is misleading. $(1234)(567890)$ is an element of order $12$ in $A_{10}$ and has a $4$-cycle in the cycle decomposition. You have to look at the whole thing - with a $4$-cycle and an odd cycle, the odd cycle is an even permutation, and the product is therefore an odd permutation, and not in $A_{10}$.

Comment: The topic about being odd and even number of cycles...do you happen to know where I can go to briefly read up on it?  My pdf doesn't have anything about this except even is negative and odd is positive.

Comment: @MarkBennet: my original message is only about the order of a product of permutations, being the lcm of the orders; it was not about $A_10$. But you are right about my comment being missleading.